# Is Elliot Haughin's Twitter library for CodeIgniter the best or is there any other?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I'm coding a new website that has heavy Twitter integration, a blog and a few other custom components. I'll be using PHP and CodeIgniter, because I like the two. Since the user sign-up and authentication is solely Twitter-based, I'll be using a Twitter library for CI. Elliot Haughin's seems like the obvious choice, but I want to know if there are any others out there.

So which Twitter library would you recommend for CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used that library with great success. I haven't found any other and because I didn't have any problems, I didn't look for any other.

If you find another Twitter PHP library, it would be trivial to modify it for use with CodeIgniter.